# How to use select fileter in camunda table?

Tags: javascript, angular, camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to use select tags inside my form and after filetering by it’s value I should get only filtered values in my selectedDocuments array , I have made this in javascript but I want to implement this logic in angular cam-sdk-form :slight_smile:

here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#mySelector').change(function() {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        $('table')[selection ? 'show' : 'hide']();

        if (selection) {
            $.each($('#myTable tbody tr'), function(index, item) {
                $(item)[$(item).is(':contains(' + selection + ')') ? 'show' : 'hide']();
            });
        }

    });
});
```

here is my  html  code:

```
<select>
     <option value='important'>აირჩიე</option>
   <option value='very important'>very important</option>
    <option value='middle important'>middle important</option>
    <option value='not so important'>not so important</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<table name="table" id="myTable" class="table table-hover  table-list-search" data-table="order-table" style="width:100%;" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:80px; height:25px;"><input style="width:25px; height:25px;" type="checkbox" id="checkAll" ng-click="selectAll()" /></th>

            <th style="width:140px;">id</th>
            <th style="width:305px;">organizationNameEN</th>
            <th style="width:305px;">organizationNameGE</th>
            <th style="width:305px;">priority</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in jsonData">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="sync(selected[item.id],item)" ng-checked="isChecked(item.id)" name="checkData" ng-model="selected[item.id]" ng-false-value="undefined" /></td>

            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.organizationNameEN}}</td>
            <td>{{item.organizationNameGE}}</td>
            <td>{{item.priority}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="toggle($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any idea how can I implement this logic( I mean selection filter ) in angular?
when I filter table like this:

[image]

I want to choose only selected value on main checkbox click and put this data in `selectedDocuments`, How should I implement this logic inside my table?